envío de datos a un archivo csv
Tengo una plataforma en la que hay varias páginas con tablas de datos. Los usuarios deberían de poder exportar los datos de la tabla a un archivo csv. Tendrían que poder exportar o todo o los marcados. Cuando marco las filas de la tabla que quiero exportar me sale el error de que no hay datos para exportar, por lo que hay algo que no veo y está mal en el código. ¿Podríais ayudarme?
Este es  el código del archivo export_csv.php
    <?php
// Verificar si se han seleccionado casillas de verificaci贸n
if (!isset($_POST['casilla']) || !is_array($_POST['casilla']) || empty($_POST['casilla'])) {
    exit('No se ha seleccionado ningun dato para la exportacion');
}
// Incluir el archivo de conexi贸n a la base de datos
include('includes/db.php');

// Definir el delimitador y el nombre del archivo CSV
$delimiter = ",";
$filename = "leads_" . date('Y-m-d') . ".csv";

// Establecer las cabeceras para la descarga del archivo CSV
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');

// Crear un puntero de archivo
$f = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// Crear los encabezados de las columnas
$fields = array('fecha', 'descripcionLeads', 'product', 'descripcion', 'cliente', 'prescripcion', 'estado', 'valor', 'comentarios');
fputcsv($f, $fields, $delimiter);

// Preparar y ejecutar la consulta para obtener los datos de los registros marcados
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM leads WHERE id = ?';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
var_dump($_POST);
foreach ($_POST['casilla'] as $id) {
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $lineData = array($row['fecha'], $row['descripcionLeads'], $row['product'], $row['descripcion'], $row['cliente'], $row['prescripcion'], $row['estado'], $row['valor'], $row['comentarios']);
        fputcsv($f, $lineData, $delimiter);
    }
}

fclose($f);
?>

Y este es el HTML de la tabla desde la que se exportan los datos de la base de datos
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="leads">
                    <h3>Leads</h3>
                    <p>Aqu&#237; puedes ver los datos de los leads.</p>
                    <a href="formulario_lead.php" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">Nuevo Lead</a>
                 
                     <form action="export_csv.php" method="post">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mb-3" name="export_csv">Exportar a CSV</button>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control pull-left" style="width:30%" id="search" placeholder="Buscar...">
                        </div>
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="mitabla">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                   <!--- <th>ID</th> --->
                                   <th scope="col"><input type="checkbox" id="checkAllLeads"></th>
                                    <th>Fecha entrada Lead</th>
                                    <th>Descripci&#243;n del Lead</th>
                                    <th>Producto</th>
                                    <th>Descripci&#243;n</th>
                                    <th>Cliente</th>
                                    <th>Prescripci&#243;n</th>
                                    <th>Estado</th>
                                    <th>Valor</th>
                                    <th>Comentarios</th>
                                    <th>Acciones</th>
                                  
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php
                                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultLeads)) {
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                   // echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['id']) . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='casilla[]'></td>"; // Casilla de verificación en cada fila
                                    echo "<td style='width: 150px;'>" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['fecha'])) . "</td>"; // Formatear la fecha
                                    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['descripcionLead']) . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['product']) . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['descripcion']) . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['cliente']) . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['prescripcion']) . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['estado']) . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['valor']) . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['comentarios']) . "</td>";
                                     //if ($usuario_tipo !== 'normal') {
                                    echo "<td>";
                                    echo "<a href='editar_lead.php?id=" . htmlspecialchars($row['id']) . "' class='btn btn-lg btn-primary'><i class='fas fa-pencil-alt'></i> Editar</a>";
                                   // echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-m btn-danger' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#confirm-delete-" . $row['id'] . "' title='Eliminar'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i> Eliminar</button>";
                                    echo "</td>";
                                //}
                                echo "</tr>";
                                ?>
                                    <!-- Modal para borrar registros -->
                                    <div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Eliminar Registro</h4>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-body">
                                                    ¿Seguro que quieres eliminar este registro?
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                                                    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="borrar_lead.php?id=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['id']); ?>"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Borrar</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                <?php } ?>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                                     
                </div>
            </div>


Para enviar un arreglo como parte del POST, te está faltando incluir el valor que corresponde a cada checkbox, que se indica con el atributo value.
Te dejo un ejemplo sencillo en HTML y un pequeño script PHP que recoge los valores enviados. Si lo estudias, vas a poder ajustar tanto tu script que produce la página, como el que exporta al archivo CSV.
Este formulario tiene una tabla, similar a la tuya, con una cabecera que permite indicar que se desea exportar todos los registros, y 4 filas identificadas con los valores del 1 al 4, que se pueden seleccionar individualmente.
        <form action="./test.php" method="post">
          <button type="submit" name="export_csv">Exportar a CSV</button>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col"><input type="checkbox" name="checkAll">
                <th>Id</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="casilla[]" value="1"></td>
                <td>1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="casilla[]" value="2"></td>
                <td>2</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="casilla[]" value="3"></td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="casilla[]" value="4"></td>
                <td>4</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </form>

Este script recoge los valores seleccionados por el usuario y los escribe como salida:
<?php 
  $valor = "indefinido";
  if (isset($_POST['checkAll'])) {
    $valor = "todos los registros";
  } else if (isset($_POST['casilla'])) {
    $valor = "Id's seleccionados: ";
    foreach ($_POST['casilla'] as $casilla) {
      $valor .= $casilla.", ";
    }
  } 
  die($valor);
?>

Nota que en el formulario original, en el checkbox de la cabecera está haciendo falta el atributo name, que es con el que se identifica la variable en el POST.
Mi script simplemente verifica su existencia, pues esta se envía solamente si el usuario deja marcada la casilla.
De manera similar, en el arreglo casilla solamente se incluyen los valores seleccionados.
Es importante que cada elemento del arreglo casilla tenga un valor distinto (único).
Una prueba rápida me arrojó estos resultados:
 
 

gracias por la info. He intentado lo que me propones y me sigue dando error. Me sale esto - No resource with given identifier found

@Monica Quita ese var_dump($_POST); a ver si va a ser eso el problema ahora, y tampoco tengo muy claro porque pones un par de header en ese código si luego no parece que te bajes nada

Monica, dónde exactamente te sale ese mensaje? es un error 404? Si copiaste el texto del HTML tal cual, ¿te aseguraste de guardar el script con el nombre test.php en la misma carpeta dónde está el HTML?

@Monica, algún comentario o avance sobre esto?

@jachguate, perdón por tardar en contestar. Al final el error estaba en el lugar donde tengo puestos los scripts de datatables.
